# Select Data using date between operator and two unconnected tables

Tags: date, between

I am tryin to resolve this situation. The following piece of code works ok .

```
SELECT FISCAL_START, DESCRIPTION,
       CASE WHEN FISCAL_START BETWEEN DATE'2014-03-31' AND DATE'2014-09-29' THEN DESCRIPTION
            ELSE 'Test Failed'
       END 
FROM GL_PERIOD
```

what I am trying to achieve is as follows instead of the hard coded dates of 2014-03-31 and 2014-09-29..need to replace those with column names `FISCAL_START` and `FISCAL_END` dates from an unconnected view call `WORK`.

Psuedo code is as follow s...

Show Description from `GL_PERIOD` where `ENTER_DATE` (which is in `WORK` view) is between `FISCAL_START` and `FISCAL_END`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add samples of the table, view and required result? 2-3 rows each. also mark wich DB you are using.

Comment: SrNo. FiscalStart FiscalEnd Description

Comment: SNo.- FisStart    -  FisEnd  -   Descripton                                                                                                                             1    -      01/04/2021- 04/30/2021 - Apr2021                                                                                        2       -   01/05/2021 - 05/31/2021 - May2021                                                                              3     -     01/06/2021 - 06/30/2021-  Jun2021                                                                                     GL_period

Comment: SrNo       Entry_Date  Work OrderNumber   Balance                                                                                                                                                      1            04/04/2021       SR123456               10.00$                                                                  2            04/05/2021      SR12789                   15.00$                                                                   3            15/06/2021       SR18960                   23.00 $                                                              using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this, I just continue your query to add the missing piece:

Here is sqlfiddle that will show you live example: [fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2abf7/13)

```
SELECT "FisStart", "Descripton",
       CASE WHEN "Entry_Date" 
             BETWEEN "FisStart"
               AND "FisEnd"
         THEN "Descripton"
         ELSE 'Test Failed'
       END 
FROM GL_PERIOD
INNER JOIN WORK USING USING ("SrNo")
```

Comment: Unfortunately the SrNo column is not the primary key for the WORK Table . I really wish it was ..it would have been a straight join then but it is not . Thank you so much Yair I for taking the time to answer the question. Anything else you can think of ?

Comment: can you add an example from the data you wrote abouve what will be the result after you run your query?

Comment: this is it here. 
                                                                                                                                    
Select v.* ,(

Select Description

from GL_PERIOD g

where


ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN g.FISCAL_START AND g.FISCAL_END


) Period_description


FROM VIEW_WIP_VAL_DETAILS v